# TypeError: Object is not a function at Object.<anonymous> when constructing Javascript w/ new

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've put together a little code in one file, which is below:

```
var exports = Symphonize;

function Symphonize(generation_specification) {
    this.generate_spec = function(){
        return generation_specification;
    }
}
```

When I start another JavaScript file in the same project and require the code like so:

```
var symphonize = require('../bin/symphonize');
var Symp = new symphonize({"test":"test1"});
```

It throws the error:

> /Users/adron/Codez/symphonize/tests/symphonize.js:8
>
> var Symp = new symphonize({"test":"test1"});
>
> ```
>           ^ TypeError: object is not a function at Object.<anonymous>
> ```

Is there another way I should be constructing this? I just want the "symphonize" code to require a simple object (an object of configuration that will be JSON) before any functions on that code are called.

Comment: This should probably be moved to SO.

Comment: you're right. I've since stopped posting said items here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When setting the exports something you must do module.exports = Something.  You should do something like :

```
module.exports = Symphonize;
```

If you had Symphonize as a property on the exports module.exports is not needed

```
exports.Symphonize = Symphonize;
```

Use it in a file.

```
var Symphonize = require('../bin/symphonize').Symphonize
```

Also `var exports` is kind of ambiguous statement in Node.